# How to remove string outside of any html tag? A library left just the closing tag of html comment

Tags: javascript, html

Here I am with a text --> outside of any markup tags. Basically looks like this:

```
<div> 
  hey 
</div>
-->
<div>
  oh no
</div>
```

Is there any way of removing this string through js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

```js
console.log("Removing text:", document.querySelector("div").nextSibling.textContent);
document.querySelector("div").nextSibling.textContent = "";
```

```html
<div> 
  hey 
</div>
-->
<div>
  oh no
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS< works like a wonder, I have been googling for hours!

Comment: @FilipSikora No problem.